# How to realloc a memory? I keep getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc, pass-by-reference

I keep geeting a segfault in the main function. I create a pointer to a struct I created and I pass it's reference to another function which allocates and reallocates memory. Then accessing it in the main function (where it was originally defined) causes a segfault.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char desc[20];
  int nr;
} Kap;

void read(Kap *k);

int main(void) {
  Kap *k = NULL;
  read(k);

  printf("__%s %d\n", k[4].desc, k[4].nr);
  return 0;
}

void read(Kap *k) {
  int size = 3;
  k = (Kap*) calloc(size, sizeof(Kap));

  k[0].nr = 1;
  k[1].nr = 2;
  k[2].nr = 3;

  strcpy(k[0].desc, "hello0");
  strcpy(k[1].desc, "hello1");
  strcpy(k[2].desc, "hello2");

  size *= 2;
  k = (Kap*) realloc(k, sizeof(Kap)*size);
  if(k == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  k[3].nr = 4;
  k[4].nr = 5;
  k[5].nr = 6;

  strcpy(k[3].desc, "hello3");
  strcpy(k[4].desc, "hello4");
  strcpy(k[5].desc, "hello5");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: try printing the value of k in the main() before and after read(). The values should change right? But they don't.

Comment: Use format `"%p"` to print a pointer. Don't forget to cast to void* or char* before.

Comment: Remember, every function in C does pass-by-value. That means that if you pass it a pointer, the function actually receives a duplicate of that pointer. In many cases this is OK because a pointer and its duplicate will point to the same space. In this case its not OK because you want the pointer `k` in main to point somewhere else after `read` is called. However, `read` can only operate on the duplicate of `k`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of the problem you are having:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int x)
{
    x = 10;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    func(x);
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

The same reason `x` does not change is the reason that `k` does not change in your program.  A simple way to fix it is this:

```
Kap *read()
{
    Kap *k = calloc(...);
    ...
    k = realloc(k, ...);
    ...
    return k;
}

int main()
{
    Kap *k = read();
    ...
}
```

Comment: You guys are awesome! :) I didn't thought it this way. That's the reason why realloc *returns* the pointer instead of changing it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ctwx It's because of the way pointers work in C. For realloc to change the pointer, it would need a different interface. It would need to accept a *pointer to* the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not passing the pointer back to `main()`. Try something like this instead:

```
Kap * read();

int main(void) {
  Kap *k = read();

  printf("__%s %d\n", k[4].desc, k[4].nr);
  return 0;
}

Kap * read() {
    ... everything else you're already doing ...
    return k;
}
```

The code you showed passes a pointer by value into `read()`. The subroutine can use that pointer (though it's kind of useless since its local copy is immediately changed), however changes made within `read()` do not bubble back to its caller.

My suggestion is one method of allowing `read()` to send the new pointer back up, and it's probably the right method to choose. Another method is to change `read()`s signature to be `void read(Kap **);`, where it will receive a pointer to a pointer -- allowing it to modify the caller's pointer (due to being passed by reference).